# Parsley 2.0.0-rc5 custom validator not firing

Tags: validation, parsley.js

I'm simply trying to add a custom validator to the Parsley config. The default validators are working but my custom one won't fire. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5brg/2/)

The script (simplified)

```
$('#form').parsley({
validators: {
  custom: function () {
    return {
      validate: function (eleVal, attrVal) {
        return false;
      },            
    };
  }
},
messages: {
    custom: "Custom validator message"
}
});
```

The HTML (simplified)

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-custom="true" required />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I followed [these docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html). Note that by removing the the `required` attribute, you have to add `data-parsley-validate-if-empty`. I just put `required` in to demonstrate that the default validators work.

Has anyone else run into this or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right for `data-parsley-validate-if-empty` if you remove `required` validator, along with your custom one.

But look at this extra validator defined here: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/extra/validator/dateiso.js

or this doc here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-craft

You have the wrong syntax for your validator, the validation function must be in a `fn` key and a priority defined. That way it should work.

Best